# SQL Server Management Studio 2016 creates project all the time

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I've recently upgraded SSMS 2014 to 2016 and what's bugging me is that whenever I want to quit it, it always asks me to save Solution even though I didn't create one.

[image]

How do I disable this check?

Comment: Have you already found and ticked the box shown here? http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56629/3690

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the tick box (also mentioned in ag93's answer) doesn't do it. That disables the prompt for unsaved files - it doesn't stop SSMS creating a solution and prompting to save that.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've tried that one, thank you. Paul Spangle is correct, it disables prompt for unsaved files, but not entire solution.

Comment: I can't repro your problem by any settings. Try to reset current settings. Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings.

Comment: Perhaps it was fixed by latest update.